# Quasi-isometric rigidity of certain products of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G_1,G_2$ be two Gromov-hyperbolic groups. If $G_1\times \Bbb{Z}$ is quasi-isometric to $G_2\times \Bbb{Z}$, must it be true that $G_1$ is quasi-isometric to $G_2$?

This is similar to the classic topology problem where crossing two non-homeomorphic spaces with $\Bbb{R}$ can create two homeomorphic spaces which are homeomorphic.

Comment: Yes, this is proven in our papers with Leeb and Kleiner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Kapovich and Leeb *[On asymptotic cones and quasi-isometry classes of fundamental groups of 3-manifolds](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/KL_1995.pdf)*, or Kapovich, Kleiner and Leeb
*[Quasi-isometries and the de Rham decomposition](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/kkl.pdf)*. This result can be also proven using the arguments of Eleanor Rieffel in *[Groups quasi-isometric to $H^2\times R$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005252)* (Journal of the London Mathematical Society **64** Issue 1 (2001) 44–60 doi:[10.1017/S0024610701002034](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0024610701002034)) which avoid asymptotic cones (in the case you do not accept the Axiom of Choice).